# Selenium + Python. Тестирование верстки

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, pycharm

Есть задача следующего характера: в рамках регрессионного тестирования пройтись по страницам и проверить верстку.
Трудность в том, что текстовое наполнение страниц может отличатся, по этому просто сравнение изображений не подойдет.

- Можно ли сравнивать некоторые параметры присвоенные элементам
  страницы, их положение и прочее?
- Или возможно есть другой вариант?

Comment: *проверить верстку* на что?

Comment: на соответствие с некоторым эталоном.

Comment: ...по каким характеристикам?

Comment: допустим, что в идеале кнопки должны быть расположенным на определенном расстоянии друг от друга, боковая панель должна быть размера n пикселей. Каков "идеал" мы знаем, но как это проверить автоматически?

Comment: Вы опишите в вопросе, какие у вас формальные критерии проверки вёрстки. Ну, на паре примеров.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Находите элементы средствами Селениума, а потом передаете их в выполняемый средствами Селениума же Javascript отсюда: http://javascript.ru/ui/offset

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное! То что надо.